# How to make msi block installing to ProgramFiles folder?

Tags: windows, installation, deployment, windows-installer, jpackage

I made the msi package to allow the user to choose installation directory for the application.

I want the user to only download the application where it doesn't need read write permissions from the user, like `%APP_DATA%/Roaming/my_app_example_name`.
The reason being that the application has a self update mechanism and updates itself when it detects a new version on the server. The update itself doesn't use an msi launcher, it just downloads the new version of the app from the server using a http request, and replaces the old files.

.

.

---

**For example**, in the popular game [spiral knights](https://www.spiralknights.com/), they implemented this mechanism like this:

[image: asdfasdf]

**Here, you can see that the default installtation directory is the Appdata folder**

---

[image]
**If i change the installation directory to ProgramFiles, and try to install, I get this error :**

[image]
**It effectively blocks installation to the directory simply because it doesn't have permissions to create a folder from the installer itself, there.**

I would like to implement the same mechanism, or something similar, because I think this is a very elegant solution to my problem. So any ideas on how to do this?

(By the way, I'm using jpackage to create the msi launchers)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--win-per-user-install` option with jpackage.

> On Windows, the default is c:\Program Files\application-name; if the
> --win-per-user-install option is used, the default is C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\application-name

More details on options at [jpackage docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/basic-packaging.html#GUID-EB1303BE-292F-4FEE-B91E-3C9CC367324B)

Comment: This worked for me. It blocks the installation to ProgramFiles folder just like I wanted. I suspect the installer for the game I mentioned also used the same feature. Thanks